# How to avoid InValidClientError with requests-oauthlib token fetching?

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I'm using the standard oauth2 web flow example from [requests-oauthlib](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/real_world_example.html) to get a token from QuickBooks Online's API but whilst I've successfully redirected to the QBO site, authorised and has a code returned to request a token I am getting a:

> oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientError

Error when I am actually making the token request.  Having googled a lot it seems like I am not authorising correctly.  QBO says the actual request might look like the following:

```
POST https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic UTM0dVBvRDIwanp2OUdxNXE1dmlMemppcTlwM1d2
    NzRUdDNReGkwZVNTTDhFRWwxb0g6VEh0WEJlR3dheEtZSlVNaFhzeGxma1l
    XaFg3ZlFlRzFtN2szTFRwbw==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: oauth.platform.intuit.com
Body: grant_type=authorization_code&
code=L3114709614564VSU8JSEiPkXx1xhV8D9mv4xbv6sZJycibMUI&
redirect_uri=https://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect
```

And that I need to generate the authorization headers like this:

"Basic " + base64encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)

I've created the above like this:

```
auth_code = client_id + ":" + client_secret
auth_code = base64.b64encode(bytes(auth_code, 'utf-8'))
auth_code = auth_code.decode('utf-8')
```

But passing this through in the token code like:

```
token = qbo.fetch_token(token_url, code=code, authorization_response=redirect_uri, headers={'Authorization' : auth_code})
```

Resulted in the InvalidClientError message.  I feel like I'm really close but failing at the final oauth2 hurdle but can someone help me authorise for the token please?

Many thanks,
John

------ edit 1 -----

Thanks stovfl, that's super helpful and I've tried a couple of new things now based on your advice.  I've just updated the code so that it reads like this:

```
headers = {'Accept':'application/json'}
headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
body = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + code + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri_token
token = qbo.fetch_token(token_url, auth=auth, body=body, headers=headers)
```

That produced another error:

> ValueError: Please supply either code or authorization_response parameters.

Checking the actual oauth library code it's mandatory to give the code/authresponse so I updated again to get the code from the callback and use it in my fetch_token request:

```
all_args = request.args.to_dict()
code = all_args['code']
headers = {'Accept':'application/json'}
headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
body = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + code + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri_token
token = qbo.fetch_token(token_url, code=code, auth=auth, body=body, headers=headers)
```

I've also tried removing the code and just having in the main call so the body looks like this:

```
body = 'grant_type=authorization_code' + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri_token
```

But either way it now goes back to the previous error of:

> oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientError: (invalid_client)

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I  found I needed to include a scope parameter in the body.

Answer (score 3):

> **Question**: QuickBooks intuit Developer: **Exchange authorization code for access token**, using OAut2.0.

According to the given `Request` Example, you should do:

1. LINE: `POST https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer HTTP/1.1`

   POST to `https://oauth.plat...` HTTP Version `1.1`, Defaults using `OAuth2.fetch_token(...`.

   ```
   url_endpoint = 'https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer'
   ```
2. LINE: `Accept: application/json`

   You have to accept `application/json`, `OAuth2.fetch_token(...` accepts anything by default.
   Nothing to do, but for completeness you can define it as follows:

   ```
   headers = {'Accept':'application/json'}
   ```
3. LINE: `Authorization: Basic a2V5OnNlY3JldA==`

   It's required that you pass auth credentials in a Basic Auth header

   ```
   from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
   auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
   ```
4. LINE: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

   The `body` Data has to passed `form-urlencoded`.

   ```
   headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
   ```
5. LINE: `Host: oauth.platform.intuit.com`

   User specific, nothing to do
6. LINE: `Body: grant_type=authorization_code&code=L311...&redirect_uri=https://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect`

   Data placement in `body`.

   ```
   body = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=L311...&redirect_uri=https://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect'
   ```
7. Exchange authorization code for access token

   ```
   token = qbo.fetch_token(url_endpoint, auth=auth, body=body, headers=headers)
   ```

> **Note**: Cant't verify with QuickBooks intuit Developer but `requests` give me the following Request Message:
>
> **Request Message**:
>
> ```
> headers:
>     Accept: application/json
>     Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
>     Content-Length: 139
>     User-Agent: python-requests/2.11.1
>     Authorization:  Basic a2V5OnNlY3JldA==
>     Host:   ... omited, because user specific
>     Content-Type:   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> form:
>     grant_type: authorization_code
>     code:   L3114709614564VSU8JSEiPkXx1xhV8D9mv4xbv6sZJycibMUI
>     redirect_uri:   https://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - requests:2.11.1***